# Collision between rolling sphere and a cube

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, collision, rigid-body-dynamics

Consider a sphere (pure) rolling towards a non-moving block and colliding with its center elastically. (We are asked to find the velocity of the block after the collision)

I thought to write down the conservation of impulse:
$$m_1 v_{sphere, before}= m_1 v_{sphere, after} + m_2 v_{cube, after}$$

And the conservation of energy
$$0.5 m_1 (v_{sphere, before})^2 + 0.5 J (\frac{v_{sphere, before}}{R})^2= 0.5 m_1 (v_{sphere, after})^2 + 0.5 J (\frac{v_{sphere, after}}{R})^2 + 0.5 m_2 (v_{cube, after})^2$$

where J is the moment of inertia of the sphere.

Now on the contrary, the solution says that the **center of mass** impulse and **energy** is conserved, i.e.

$$m_1 v_{sphere, before}= m_1 v_{sphere, after} + m_2 v_{cube, after}$$
like I have and

$$0.5 m_1 (v_{sphere, before})^2 = 0.5 m_1 (v_{sphere, after})^2 + 0.5 m_2 (v_{cube, after})^2$$

I do not understand why the center of mass energy is conserved, in general it isn't: As a counterexample consider a single sphere rolling down a hill: You couldn't just consider the energy of the center of mass - you also have to consider the rotation around the center of mass (which yields $U_{grav}=T_{trans}+T_{rot}$)

Here are my questions: 1. Would my approach be correct?
2. Why is the COM energy conserved in the collision example 3. Why isnt't the COM energy conserved in my counterexample?

PS: The solution says "the rotational energy of the sphere can not be transmitted to the cube and dissipates into friction (rotation in the opposite direction of movement!)" Maybe you understand what is meant by that.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the assumption made in the given solution is that there is no friction between the the objects (sphere and block) and the ground.

That being the case there is no way to apply an external torque about the centre of mass of the sphere as the ground cannot apply a horizontal force on the sphere at the point of contact.
This means that the sphere's angular speed stays constant as does its rotational kinetic energy and it does not matter that the sphere is slipping relative to the ground as there is no frictional force between them.

If there was friction between the sphere and the ground (and/or between sphere and block) the frictional force would provide an external torque on the sphere and change its angular speed and rotational kinetic energy as you have suggested.

However, you then cannot use conservation of mechanical energy for the sphere and block system because in going from the initial state to the final state there must be slipping between the sphere and the ground as the speed of the sphere cannot change instantaneously, and hence there will be a change in the mechanical energy of the system as heat would be generated.

> the solution says that the center of mass impulse is conserved

What that means is that the impulse on the centre of mass of the sphere due to the block is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the impulse on the centre of mass of the block due to the sphere, which is Newton's third law, and if there are no horizontal external impulse acting on the sphere & block system then horizontal linear momentum is conserved.

> the solution says that energy is conserved

Energy is always conserved but in the case where there is no friction kinetic energy (both translational and rotational) is conserved but as the rotational kinetic energy of the sphere does not change then one must only need to consider translational kinetic energy.

> You couldn't just consider the energy of the center of mass - you also
> have to consider the rotation around the center of mass

In a friction-free world the sphere would slip relative to the slope and not rotate as there would be no torque about its centre of mass to change its angular speed.